# Cannot Invoke Value of type Trip into Type Json

Tags: json, swift, struct, swift3, compiler-errors

I have a struct as follows :

```
struct Trip {
    var status: Int?
    var name: Int?
    var id: Int?
    var petId: [Int]
    var timeStart: Int?
}
```

I use this struct to load data from Json using this function.

```
func startTrips( _ petIdss: [Int], callback: @escaping ApiTrip) {
    let data = ["pets" : petIdss]
    APIManager.instance.perform(call: .startTrip, with: data) { (error, json) in
        if let error = error {
            callback(error, nil)
        } else if let data = json{

            callback(nil, Trip(data))
        }

    }

}
```

But when i try to cast it's type as Trip in the callback `callback(nil, Trip(data))` 
I either get

> Missing argument for parameters

that's if i leave the struct as is or initialise the optionals. If i convert all the parmeters in the struct into optionals i get

> Cannot Invoke Value of type Trip into Type Json.

So i am not sure what's wrong here?

Comment: What is the type of ApiTrip? Please include its declaration.

Comment: typealias ApiTrip = (APIManagerError?, Trip?) -> Void

Comment: APIManagerError is error types to handle Server errors. And the Trip is the struct i posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't specify an initialiser for a struct the only one you have access to is the member wise initialiser.

What you need is to write a custom initialiser taking a JSON data parameter. This implementation uses SwiftyJSON.

Like this:

```
struct Trip {

  var status: Int?
  var name: Int?
  var id: Int?
  var petId: [Int]
  var timeStart: Int?

  init(status: Int?, name: Int?, id: Int?, petId: [Int], timeStart: Int?) {
    self.status = status
    self.name = name
    self.id = id
    self.petId = petId
    self.timeStart = timeStart
  }

  init?(_ json: JSON) {
    if let petId = json["petId"].number as? Int {
      self = Trip(status: json["status"].number as? Int, name: json["name"].number as? Int, id: json["id"] as? Int, petId: petId, timeStart: json["timeStart"] as? Int)
    } else {
      return nil
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You either need to use `try?` or put the try inside a do-catch block. And i'd also recommend making this a failable initializer instead of using dummy data if the JSON parsing fails.

Comment: What does "data" refer to. Not sure exactly how to use this?

Comment: Yes I have rewritten the initialiser to use `data` as the parameter name. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Yes. I have updated this to be a failable initialiser.

Comment: Now it's extra argument 'name' in call

Comment: @Mohamed Could you please provide more information on which line your error is being called, and check you have not altered the code/struct from the question description.

Comment: The error is on this line             self = Trip(status: JSONObject["status"], name: JSONObject["name"], id: JSONObject["id"], petId: petId, timeStart: JSONObject["timeStart"]). and i haven't changed the code above.

Comment: @Mohamed Also, have you changed your struct definition?

Comment: No, Unfortunately it has not!  No I have not changed it.

Comment: Thank you. This works without error. But in the startTrips function i get the error cannot convert value of type 'JSON' to expected argument type 'Data'

Comment: Are you using SwiftyJSON?

Comment: Yes i am using it.

Comment: Should i use anyObject instead of array?

Comment: @PranavKasetti Thank you So much for your help. You really have made my day. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Mohamed Happy to help! Please accept and upvote answer so the question can be closed.